# Initialising graph with lists input in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I am wanting create a graph like the following: `graph = {'a':{'b':10,'c':3},'b':{'c':1,'d':2},'c':{'b':4,'d':8,'e':2},'d':{'e':7},'e':{'d':9}}`

Using the following function:

```
def make_graph(start, end, cost):

    graph = {}
    values = {}
    v = len(cost)

    #print("Enter vertices(keys) : ")
    for i in range(v):
        graph.setdefault(start[i])

    edges = {}
    for x in graph:
        edges.setdefault(x)

    print(edges)
    for i in graph:
        graph[i] = edges.copy()

    print(graph)
    for i in graph:
        #print(i)
        for j in graph[i]:
            #print(j)
            var = cost
            graph[i][j] = var

        pprint.pprint(graph)
```

Each position of the list is the specified route (e.g. `start[0]`, `end[0]`, `cost[0]` could be `a`, `b`, `10`, and `start[1]`, `end[1]`, `cost[1]` could be `a`, `c`, `3` and so on)

Currently I am getting a graph that shows: `{'a':{'a':'10','3','1','2',4'... etc}`

How can I create the graph without duplicates being put in?

Comment: `{'a':'10','3','1','2',4'}` is not a valid Python dictionary. Please post the exact output you're getting

Comment: {'a':{'a':['5.5','15','16.5], 'b':['5.5','15','16.5'],'c':['5.5','15','16.5]},
{'b':{'a':['5.5','15','16.5], 'b':['5.5','15','16.5'],'c':['5.5','15','16.5]},
{'c':{'a':['5.5','15','16.5], 'b':['5.5','15','16.5'],'c':['5.5','15','16.5]}}